# Access service fabric app with different endpoints

Tags: .net, azure-service-fabric, service-fabric-stateless

I am having a cluster on which I want to deploy 2 version of same service fabric service and instantiate them as well. For ex - I have App1 of version 1.0 and App1 of version 2.0. Both of these are instantiated with fabric:/Instance1 and fabric:/Instance2 respectively.

I have changed the endpoint of both app instances in servicemanifest.xml like below.

Endpoint 1:

```
<Endpoint Name="ServiceEndpoint" Type="Input" Protocol="http" Port="8081" />
```

Endpoint 2:

```
<Endpoint Name="ServiceEndpoint" Type="Input" Protocol="http" Port="8081" />
```

Please let me know how these 2 instances running on different port with different endpoint can be accessed?

Comment: Is there anyone to comment on this, I need Help on this. Thanks!!

Comment: no answers yet. Tagging @valcav

Comment: @Vaclav Turecek Please provide your inputs here.